# Process Runtime pass input

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I have rsync command to be run in a java program...the problem i am facing is that rsync requires a password to be entered and i am not understanding how to pass this password to the rsync command to work?

Comment: can't you setup passwordless ssh between the servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was gonna post this code sample:

```
Process rsyncProc = Runtime.exec ("rsync");
OutputStreanm rsyncStdIn = rsyncProv.getOutputStream ();
rsyncStdIn.write ("password".getBytes ());
```

But [Vineet Reynolds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3916/vineet-reynolds) was ahead of me.

As Vineet Reynolds pointed out using such approach will require an additional piece of code to detect when rsync requires a password. So using an external password file seems to be an easier way.

P.S.: There may be a problem related to the encoding, it can by solved by converting the string to a byte array using appropriate encoding as described [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)).

P.P.S.: It seems that I can't yet comment an answer, so I had to post a new one.

Comment: i would like to have the first approach...can anyone tell me how do i detect when rsync asks for a password?

Comment: The code sample is too much for a comment, so I posted as [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456613/process-runtime-pass-input/7457905#7457905).

Comment: Haha, cannot fix typo. Thanks SO!

Answer (score 4):

Took me some time, but here it goes:

```
    Process ssh = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec (new String[] {"rsync", ... /*other arguments*/});
    Reader stdOut = new InputStreamReader (ssh.getInputStream (), "US-ASCII");
    OutputStream stdIn = ssh.getOutputStream ();

    char[] passRequest = new char[128];//Choose it big enough for rsync password request and all that goes before it
    int len = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        len += stdOut.read (passRequest, len, passRequest.length - len);
        if (new String (passRequest, 0, len).contains ("password:")) break;
    }

    System.out.println ("Password requested");
    stdIn.write ("your_password\n".getBytes ("US-ASCII"));
    stdIn.flush ();
```

P.S.: I don't really know how rsync works, so you may need to change it a bit - just run rsync manually from a terminal an see how exactly it requests a password.

Answer (score 2):

You can write to the output stream of the `Process`, to pass in any inputs. However, this will require you to have knowledge of `rsync`'s behavior, for you must write the password to the outputstream only when the password prompt is detected (by reading the input stream of the `Process`).

You may however, create a non-world readable password file, and pass the location of this password file using the `--password-file` option when you launch the `rsync` process from Java.

Answer (score 1):

Need not wait till the password is requested to write it to the stream. Make use of a BufferedWriter instead.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream())
);
writer.write(passwd, 0, passwd.length());
writer.newLine();
writer.close();
```

This must work.